# Create multiple sign-off options for html e-mail signature

Tags: html, email, html-email

Hopefully this is something trivial that should have an easy solution, but here is what I'm looking to achieve:

With a standard html e-mail signature I'm looking to have the option to select the sign off I want to use (I was thinking in the form of a drop down menu, but am open to suggestions).

I've tried using a simple  tag with options, but this still appears as a drop down menu when opened by the recipient. I'd like to have just the text shown, rather than also displaying the options I've chosen from.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for the help and please ask for clarifications if necessary!

Comment: What programming language is this? And could you please post the relevant code here?

Comment: which email domain are you trying to use. (like outlook, gmail or what)